# Multiple Database Design or NOT?

Tags: database

*I have a database design issue, one that has rattled my brain.*

**What is the project?**

I am designing a platform where different people register a group, each group is allowed to register their own members, it is important to keep these groups away from each other, as each are to their own, each group would have access to 65 or more tables with possibilities of 1000 of rows of data in each table, in their own database, each database is a copy of an empty master database.

**Where i am stuck.**

I do not know if this is wise cause i could end up with a 1,000 - 30,000 databases. I need to either create a database with a unique name (scenario above) or create a database with a unique environment variable, where each group has it's own environment variable.

**Where things get messy.**

Assigning each group to a unique database allows me to keep things simple, allows me to access all the data within the group relatively easy (vs searching through 1000 of groups data in one database). *a simple but not too important, but still relevant eg.* Each group can create things like their own invoices, so if all groups have unique databases then the invoice numbers would follow logically (users perspective), but if all groups are within the same database invoice numbers would not follow logically (users perspective).

**The Question Then**

Should I, or would it be wise, to create multiple database to keep my system efficient, bear in mind that there is no need to cross over from one group to another.

Comment: Have you already decided which database management system (such as relational DBMSs like Oracle, SQLServer etc) you intend to implement this on? Also, have you considered asking this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ (which may be a better site for this question)?

Comment: I'd be more thinking on things such as recovery - is there a likely scenario where you might have to restore one group's data from backups? If so, would you want to have to force all other groups to undergo the same process?

Comment: This is also a part of the problem, if something like that happens, then yes i would have to restore a particular groups data.

Comment: I am using MySql,cPanl,Linux.

Comment: To put a spanner in the works. This system is build and almost running, registration has also been build. I have set it up to copy the master database. I was about to launch, yet this morning, i woke up and it struck me, maintenance, it would be easier changing something from one database. so i am stuck now. i either include the environment variable on all tables and have all queries include the search for the environment variable and use one database OR continue with multiple databases. I donno what to do.. i appreciate all input and ask your questions away. I need to launch tomorrow.

Comment: can mysql handle 1000's / 10,000's of databases? I suppose one could always write code to add new tables to each database if need be (5 year plan, thinking ahead).

Comment: @Jacques: I have deleted my answer here, and entered a (modified) version of it as an answer to your related question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Link to the **[question at DBA.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45577/multiple-database-design-or-not)**